# copy keyword from list range

Tags: excel-formula

I've tried multiple function types, with no success.

I have a list of keywords named 'Keywords' and i have a column of string text.  For each string of text in a cell I would like to pick out the first keyword from 'Keywords' list and place in an adjacent cell.  I've been stumped for a couple days now and am reaching out for help.

Any assistance is appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INDEX with AGGREGATE:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$2:$A$4)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$2:$A$4,C2))),1)),"")
```

[image]